# How to Include Vue Component in all other components and use a method to call it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue Component `AlertSimple` that I use to show alerts. I would like to have this available in all componets automatically and call it with a simple method something like:

```js
this.$alertSimple.show(
'Alert Title', 'Alert message', 'success', 5000
)
//Args as title, message, type, timeout.
```

How do I go about that?

**This is what I have and how I am doing it currently.**

AlertSimple.vue

```js
<template>
    <div aria-live="assertive" class="...">
        <div class="...">
           
            <transition>
                <div v-if="showPopup"
                     class="..">
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <div >
                            <div >
                                <ExclamationCircleIcon v-if="type === 'error'" class="..."/>
                                <ExclamationTriangleIcon v-else-if="type === 'warn'" class="..."/>
                                <InformationCircleIcon v-else-if="type === 'info'" class="..."/>
                                <CheckCircleIcon v-else class="..."/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="...">
                                <p class="... capitalize">{{ title }}</p>
                                <p class="... normal-case">{{ content }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="...">
                                <button type="button" @click="showPopup = false"
                                        class="...">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                    <XMarkIcon class="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true"/>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    
    props: {
        title: {type: String, required: true,},
        content: {type: String, required: true,},
        type: {type: String, required: false, default: 'success'},
        show: {type: Boolean, required: false, default: false},
        timeout: {type: Number, required: false, default: 5},
    },
    data() {
        return {
            showPopup: this.show,
            timer: null
        }
    },
    watch: {
        show: function (newVal, OldVal) {
            this.showPopUp();
        },
        content: function (){
            this.showPopUp()
        }
    },

    methods: {
        showPopUp() {
            this.showPopup = true;
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.resetPopup();
        },
        resetPopup() {
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                this.showPopup = false;
            }, (this.timeout * 1000))
        }
    }

}


</script>
```

I have removed classes and other boilerplate intentionally to make it short.

Now, lets say I want to use it in `ComponentX`.

Step 1: I Import the `AlertSimple` component in it.

```html
<AlertSimple
  :title="alertState.title"
  :content="alertState.message"
  :show="alertState.showPopup"
  :type="alertState.type"
></AlertSimple>
```

Step 2: I define reactive properties for it.

```js
const alertState = reactive({
    showPopup: false,
    title: '',
    message: '',
    type: 'success',
});
```

Step 3: I define `showAlert` method

```js
function showAlert(title, message, type='success') {
    this.alertState.showPopup = true;
    this.alertState.title = title;
    this.alertState.message = message;
    this.alertState.type = type;
}
```

Finally, I call this method from different parts of the component to trigger the alert. e.g. on button clicks.

```js
 <button @click="showAlert('Warning in Data', 'Your data may have an issue', 'warn')" 
         type="button"
         class="...">
    Warn
 </button>

 <button @click="showAlert('Informative Data', 'I thought you should know this', 'info')" 
         type="button"
         class="...">
    Info
 </button>
```

I have been trying different methods like mixins to no avail, I feel like I am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a high level, you probably want to create a [Vue plugin](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html).

There are several toast notification plugins of varying complexity online. [This plugin](https://github.com/k90mirzaei/vue-toast) seems to have a fairly simple source structure, while also achieving the interface you're looking for (calling `this.$alertSimple.show()` within any other component).

I won't write out all of the code necessary, but here are some high-level snippets to get you going in the right direction:

### The Service

You already have your component, `alert-simple.vue`. Create a service/utility that mounts instances of that component using Vue's `render` and `h` functions:

```js
// alert-simple-service.js
import { render, h } from 'vue';
import AlertSimple from './alert-simple.vue';

const mountElement = (props) => {
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  let vNode = h(AlertSimple, props);

  render(vNode, el);

  // You probably want to track or return the instances you create
};

export default {
  // The interface you want to expose. For example...
  show (title, content, show, type) {
    mountElement({ title, content, show, type });
  },
  hide () {
    // And so on...
  }
}
```

### The Plugin Export

Turning the service into a plugin is pretty cut-and-dry from the Vue plugin documentation linked above. In your case:

```js
// alert-simple-plugin.js
import service from './alert-simple-service.js';

export default {
  install: (app, options) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$alertSimple = service;
  }
}
```

You would import this file wherever your app is initialized and call `app.use()` like so to register your plugin:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import alertSimplePlugin from './alert-simple-plugin.js';

const app = createApp({})

app.use(alertSimplePlugin, {
  /* optional options */
})
```

Comment: Let me know if any of those snippets or links are not clear, or if I misinterpreted your request from the question. There is a lot more to plugins than I outlined above, but hopefully those snippets (plus that toast notification plugin on Github) get you some momentum in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, Your answer is clear but I think am missing something, I have created the plugin and service as indicated but am still getting an error when I hit `this.$alertSimple.show(title, message, true, type);` . Here is the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')`

Comment: You're absolutely correct: I had missed the `.config.globalProperties` piece of the plugin install function. (It was listed correctly in the Vue documentation, but I did not copy it over successfully.) I've edited the post with that missing piece!

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Here is a pen of my initialization app.js: https://codepen.io/john-murithi/pen/QWOrZxR
Pen for Service: https://codepen.io/john-murithi/pen/yLMLVWX
Pen for Plugin: https://codepen.io/john-murithi/pen/PobxYNO

Comment: I am not familiar with setting up Vue plugins within Inertia. My best guess is that there is some quirk with adding plugins specifically within their system. Try adding a `config.globalProperties` value directly within your `setup` function as shown [here](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/287) (just for debugging purposes), but beyond that I'd recommend asking a new question with Inertia tagged.

Comment: Thank you for trying, I still believe what you have provided is correct for the plain Vue App so I will mark it as the answer and then ask a question for InertiaJS with proper tags.

Comment: No worries, and thank you for the well-written question and follow-ups! Best of luck moving forward!